# Abrir Links Externos WebView

Tags: android-studio, webview

Como faço pra inserir o código  @Override sem gerar erro: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override

No android studio ele informa que o erro está no final do código...

```js
package in.learncodewithrk.webview_example;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    String url = "https://maisdocente.com/";

    //    final String filename= URLUtil.guessFileName(URLUtil.guessUrl(url));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       // getSupportActionBar().hide();

        webView = findViewById(R.id.web);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe);


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewclient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        webView.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                },  3000);
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
        );

        //  ==================== START HERE: THIS CODE BLOCK IS TO ENABLE FILE DOWNLOAD FROM THE WEB. YOU CAN COMMENT IT OUT IF YOUR APPLICATION DOES NOT REQUIRE FILE DOWNLOAD. IT WAS ADDED ON REQUEST ======//

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            String fileName = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        //  ==================== END HERE: THIS CODE BLOCK IS TO ENABLE FILE DOWNLOAD FROM THE WEB. YOU CAN COMMENT IT OUT IF YOUR APPLICATION DOES NOT REQUIRE FILE DOWNLOAD. IT WAS ADDED ON REQUEST ======//



    }

    public class myWebViewclient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/lost.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.contains("https://m.sendspace.com/") || (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/file/") )) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex

            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        mWebView.stopLoading();


        return false;
    }

}
```